# Error en la conversión de datos- SSIS, SQL Server

Tags: sql, ssis

buen día,
estoy tratando de exportar una tabla desde sql server a un archivo txt a través de SSIS, pero el problema es que existe un campo en el cual se dejan observaciones y muchas veces dejan emojis o caracteres raros, por lo cual me da un error el Integration services y no completa el exporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco sus aportes para poder entender de que manera se pueden solucionar estos casos.

Gracias!

Comment: no tenemos mucho cómo ayudarte si no nos dices ni el tipo de dato de la columna destino, ni cual es el tipo de datos que estás usando en SSIS para esa columna en el flujo de datos

Comment: Hola, el tipo de dato es un nvarchar y estoy convirtiendolo en ssis a un DT_WSTR (4000)

Comment: Es probable que la definición del archivo tenga un tipo de dato más corto.